# Scala using Implicit with Self Types

Tags: scala, mixins, implicit-conversion, self-type

I have a implicit class which requires a user database. I want to use self-type in implicit class so I can switch implementation of database in testing scope to the mocked version. How do I mix-in database provider in this case? For example, I want user of RuchUser to not worry about having to mix-in UserDatabaseProvider by providing default mix-in. So user can just do `User("name").userContext` and do the same at testing scope where I will provide default mix-in to use mocked database provider?

```
case class User(name: String)

object User {
  implicit class RichUser(self: User) { this: UserDatabaseProvider =>
     def userContext: String = this.getUserContext(self.name)
  }
}

// Usage of Rich user should be below as I want to provide already mixed-in implicit
import User._
val context = User("name").uerContext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating quite a bit.

```
case class User(name: String) {
  def context()(implicit db: UserDatabaseProvider): UserContext = {
    db.getUserContext(name)
  }
}
```

I would go to further suggest the cake pattern may be more applicable here than using implicits.

```
class UserService extends UserDatabaseProvider {
  def context(user: User): UserContext = getUserContext(user.name)
}
class TestUserService extends UserService with TestDatabase
```

Let "right-most wins" diamond resolution in Scala do the job for you.